# OpenGL rendering different objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have some problem with render my solar system.

I have small objects and a large object, which is located at a distance 10e9 times greater than small objects. How I can render all that? (I want see the Sun, when I around my small objects)

```
glm::perspective(m_fInitialFoV, 4.0f / 3.0f, near, far);
```

If far/near is to big, all object are flickering.

Comment: You can't use astronomical distances in graphics calculations; there's simply not enough precision in a double to handle them.

Comment: To refine on what @ColonelThirtyTwo: wrote: When doing astronomical renderings it usually boils down to assuming all objects being at infinity and be concerned only the angular directions.

Comment: And if the next option is possible?:
If the subject is too far away, the transfer and scale  the object on the radius vector of the camera-object in such a way as to be visible. If camera was move, projection was move too.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is to group objects by scale and render them separately. For example, the solar system could use as unit the scale of Earth, which is `6378.1 km` radius, and `147.09x10^6 km` far away from the sun.

Normalizing these around the Earth's radius, we get:

```
Earth's Radius: 1.0 unit
Distance from sun: 23061.72 units
```

Same principle of normalization applies to other solar system bodies:

```
Venus' Radius: 0.9488405638 units
Distance from sun: 16851.41 units

Pluto's Radius: 0.186105580 units
Distance from sun: 695633.4 units
```

You should also setup your depth to incorporate such numbers. As long as bodies have a lot of space between themselves, no errors and z-fighting should occur.
So:

1. Render the 'big' group first. (big depth range)
2. Then clear only the depth of your screen.
3. Then render objects that are small and close to the camera, such as asteroids, spaceships, etc. Things that do not need such large
   numbers. (here use a substantially smaller depth range)
4. You're done.

As you can see, you could group the scene based on scale and on multiple levels. You could, for example, get the list of coordinates for the local group of stars, render them first as points, clear the depth, then render the bodies of the system you are into, clear the depth again, and render the local objects at your position. You should also consider, that a planet like Pluto is barely visible from Earth, so you can simply use a lot smaller depth range for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution than multi-pass rendering would be to use a logarithmic depth buffer. At the cost of some precision, you can expand your available depth range exponentially. Take a look here for more info: http://outerra.blogspot.com/2009/08/logarithmic-z-buffer.html